# Set xml file name according to type

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, filenames

I'd like to create an xml file with the filename set according to the type chosen.

```
If type.Value = "H" Then
            fileName = "Hotels.xml"
        ElseIf type.Value = "F" Then
            fileName = "Flights.xml"
        ElseIf type.Value = "T" Then
            fileName = "Tours.xml"
        End If

xmlFile = Server.MapPath("") + "/files/" + fileName
DT.WriteXml(xmlFile, XmlWriteMode.DiffGram)
```

But the fileName encounters 'variable fileName is used before it has been assigned a value. I tried changing the xmlFile part to the top of the conditions, but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have not initialized the "fileName" string variable before using it in the if condition. Initialize it to null when you first declare it like below. The code is in C# as I am a little weak in VB.NET but I think you understood what I meant here.

```
string fileName = null;
```

In VB.NET it should be (I think)

```
Dim fileName As String = Nothing
```

Hope this helped.

Regards,

Samar

Comment: No Problem. Glad I could help. :) I will just edit the post to include VB.NET way of initializing so that others could benefit from it.